# Full selector string or this.find and selector string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Both work, but is there any advantage / dis-advantage of using one over the other ?

```
$("#" + this.id + " > ul > li.active:first")
```

vs

```
$(this).find(" > ul > li.active:first")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second selector works, I'd go with that instead of concatenating the ID into the first selector (looks ugly) and making jQuery look for that same element ID again (redundant).

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this... I think.

```
$(" > ul li.active:first", this);
```